# C# application UI Text localization not working

Tags: c#, windows, localization, globalization

I have a context menu application where I have a base project SampleContextMenu.Base and a child project SampleContextMenu.Menu.

In SampleContextMenu.Menu, I have created a context menu for which I set a text like this.

```
sampleItem.Text = "Open In";
```

Now I want to globalize this string. So I created 3 resource files called UiStrings.resx, UiStrings.de-DE.resx, and UiStrings.fr-FR.resx.

In the class SampleContextMenu.cs, I have the following code now,

```
   // Resource path
    private string strResourcesPath = Application.StartupPath + "/Resources";
    // string to store current culture which is comon in all the forms
    private string strCulture = "en-US";
    //resourcemanager which retrivesthe strings
    //from the resource files
    private static ResourceManager rm;

    private void GlobalizeApp()
    {
        SetCulture();
        SetResource();
    }
    private void SetCulture()
    {
        CultureInfo objCI = new CultureInfo(strCulture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = objCI;
    }
    private void SetResource()
    {
        rm = new ResourceManager("SampleContextMenu.Menu.UiStrings", typeof(SampleContextMenu).Assembly);
    }
        protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {
                // some code to create menu
                strCulture = Read("language");

                GlobalizeApp();

                sampleItem.Text = rm.getString("0000");
      }
```

**EDIT**
For me now even if the language is de or fr, it still shows stirng for the default( i.e. En)

Comment: this msdn link should help you out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.110).aspx if you are doing localization you should really be using resx files rather than txt files to store you data.

Comment: Hi David, Now another problem, it picks up only en texts? Could you please check my edit and let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: got the problem!... I was not setting the CurrentUICulture!!